# Configuring Apache 2 ubuntu default page and Xampp in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apache, svn, xampp, ubuntu-14.04

I've installed Xampp 5.6.11-0 in Ubuntu 14.04 OS.
Then few days ago I install and configure apache subversion.

Now, when i try to run xampp via terminal (with command : sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start), the xampp failed to run and it shows following message in terminal :

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 5.6.11-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache...fail.
XAMPP:  Another web server is already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...fail.
XAMPP:  Another FTP daemon is already running.
```

When i visit `localhost` in my browser, it display "Apache 2 Ubuntu default page".
How can i run my Xampp again? Is there any missed configuration?
Any help/clue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to i install Xampp and also Apache2 web server. So if you have the same problem with me, here's the solution.

Try to stop apache if you want to start Xampp ->> `sudo service apache stop`

Then run xampp ->> `sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

Now when you visit `localhost` it will show xampp Welcome page!

Answer (score 0):

Probably an already used port. Probably the 80.

Run: netstat -tulpn to check what ports are in use, and then free the one you need by running kill  where  is the process number in the last column of the output of the first command.